# Qual a diferença entre o preg_split e o explode?

Tags: php

Qual a diferença entre as funções `preg_split` e `explode`? Quando usar uma ou outra?
Me deparei com esse código e estou querendo entender o seu funcionamento.

```
function consulta_header_grid($campos){
  $linha = preg_split('/[\n]/', $campos, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  foreach($linha as $linha){
    $colunas = explode("    ", $linha);
    $header[$colunas[0]] = $colunas[0] . ";" . $colunas[1] . ";" . $colunas[2];
  }

  return $header;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A principal diferença entre a [`explode();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) e [`preg_split();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-split.php) é que você pode usar [expressão regular](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/regex.examples.php) na `preg_split();`, porém, segundo o *stack.com*, o explode normalmente é mais rápido ([segue a referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303235/in-php-which-is-faster-preg-split-or-explode)).

Em resumo, se for uma filtragem mais complexa use o `preg_split();`, se for algo mais simples use o `explode();`.

Nesse seu exemplo, ele usa o `preg_split();` com o `"\n"` parar quebra a cada linha, e o explode("   "), para gera um vetor com base no espaços.

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudo muito.

Answer (score 0):

Ambos são usados ​​para *dividir* uma *string* em um *array*, a diferença é que `split()` usa o *"pattern"*, enquanto `explode()` usa *string*. `explode()` é mais rápido do que `split()` porque não corresponde à *string* com base na expressão regular.

Comment: Vlw brother, agora deu para entender o codigo